# Cambiar el formato de una parametro date en JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper, parametros

me encuentro haciendo un programa de un estacionamiento en netbeans y es la primera vez que utilizo JasperReport; lo uso para hacer un corte de caja dentro del programa pero tengo problemas para hacer la consulta. Para hacer el corte de caja muestro todos los autos que hayan salido el dia que se hace el corte, sin embargo el formato de fecha con el que guardo su fecha de salida es "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s" y los parametros de tipo date registran  "d/M/y" asi que quisiera saber como poder cambiar el formato de fecha de este paramatero o de que otra manera podria hacer esta consulta.
[image: Consulta en JasperReport]

Answer (score 0):

1. Primero arrastra el "Field" al diseñador del reporte en donde colocarás el campo para mostrar.
2. Da click al campo para seleccionarlo y te aparezcan en la zona derecha de tu pantalla todas las propiedades de tu campo.
3. En donde dice "Pattern" das click en el cuadrado con los 3 puntos, ahi hay diferentes categorias para dar formato, la que te interesa a ti es la de "Date" y te aparecera un cuadro como la siguiente imagen. Seleccionas el formato que necesitas, o en su defecto esta "Custom Format" para que realices el patron de la manera que deseas.

[image: Imagen de Patron]

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, acabe de utilizar lo que me indicaste en tu respuesta pero eso solo  me ha mostrado la fecha con el formato que quiero en el reporte pero el parametro sigue manteniendo su formato original y no funciona para hacer la consulta select * from registro where fecha_salida like parametro me podrias ayudar con eso?